# Cannot search/filter tag synonyms

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-synonyms

<strike>When trying to [search/filter tag synonyms by a common phrase `c`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=c), or by [any other term](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=html), the results are not narrowed down.</strike> (fixed)

Additionally, when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, trying to search from the "suggested" tab results in being booted back to the "all" tab - like before, with no narrowed results. EDIT: This behavior is also exhibited on the "all" tab - once the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is hit, the tag-narrowing is reset, despite the query parameter being present in the URL bar.

Comment: The link doesn't work, but typing `c` into the filter field does.  I don't get booted from the Suggested tab when I type into the filter field.

Comment: Apparently the filtering has been fixed now, though hitting enter, after typing still will send me back to the "all" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disabled `submit` for the form. Agree the enter functionality was really confusing.